# Python PATH is taken over by anaconda even I've modified .bash_profile

Tags: python, anaconda

`which python` gives `/Users/liuzhiyu/opt/anaconda3/bin/python3.8`

My `.bash_profile` :

```sh
# Setting PATH for Python 3.8

PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:${PATH}$"
export PATH

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
source "$HOME/.cargo/env"

# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/Users/liuzhiyu/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/liuzhiyu/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/Users/liuzhiyu/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/Users/liuzhiyu/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

As I know, `PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:${PATH}$"` sets the path for python3.8.

I've tried to comment the lines involving anaconda, but it didn't work.

System: MacOS 12.0.1

Comment: I do know that the default shell for macOS Monterey isn't bash, but which shell is part of the user configuration. If this is being run, the __conda_setup variable has some commands that adjust the value of `PATH`, The entire block within the `conda initialize` comments need to be commented out as well..

Comment: Do not comment out the Conda initialization code. Instead follow the duplicate advice and configure Conda not to auto-activate **base**.

Comment: @BenY that is not a good suggestion

Comment: My interpretation of "I've tried to comment the lines" was that he only did a few of the lines. With the information given, there's not a whole lot we can infer, but my understanding is that he didn't want it to run Anaconda.